# im having problems with the parallelogram pattern it go from positive to Negative

Tags: python

Write a program that prints the following parallelogram pattern given the following two inputs. Hint: Use nested loops.

Example 1

This program will output a parallelogram.
How long do you want each side to be?
5
Please enter the character you want it to be made of:
*
Parallelogram:

```
*

**

***

****

*****
 

****

  ***

   **

    *
```

Example 2

This program will output a parallelogram.
How long do you want each side to be?
8
Please enter the character you want it to be made of:
@
Parallelogram:

```
@
    
@@
    
@@@
    
@@@@
    
@@@@@
    
@@@@@@
    
@@@@@@@
    
@@@@@@@@
     
@@@@@@@
      
@@@@@@
       
@@@@@
        
@@@@
         
@@@
          
@@
           
@
```

my apologies  here my code id tried

```
"This program will output a parallelogram."
 rows =int (input( "How long do you want each side to be ? "))
"Please enter the character you want it to be made of: "
c = ()
  #loop
for i in range (rows,0,-1):
     for space in range (1, rows -i):
       print (" c,", end="")
       for j in range (i,2*1-1):   
           print (" c,",end="")
       for j in range (1,i-1):
        print ("c,",end="")
        print()
```

Comment: What is the question? StackOverflow is not to ask someone else to do you homework...

Comment: help to do it yes

Comment: Don't understand  that just not how you do homework

Answer (score 0):

because this is a homework question i will not post actual code but only explain how to do this in words.

I'm not sure if the following is actually what you want to achieve (Some of your code is a bit messed up).

your parallelogram consists of two parts:

- one where it gets larger and
- one where it gets smaller.

If you want to create a shape that gets larger, you need to draw more characters each line:
In the first line you want 1 character, then 2 and so on until you hit `n`, the max number of characters (inputted by user).

then you want to get the shape smaller by drawing less characters each line:
In the first line you want `n-1` characters to be drawn, then `n-2` and so on until you hit 1.
You may want to have the right side to be horizontal (one example by you has this, the other doesn't). For this you need to draw spaces in front of the characters (1 space in the first row, 2 in the second ...).